# Adjusting text view height while editing Swift

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, textview

I am not using a table view and my text view is not inside a table view cell. I have been researching this for days but nothing has worked and most answers relate to changing the height of a text view inside a table view cell or only work for iOS 6 and prior.

I am trying to adjust the height of a text view while the user types in it.
I and using auto layout and have an outlet connected to the text view height constraint and I have tried to get this working by altering that but it doesn't have any affect.

If anybody has gotten this working on iOS 7 or newer and can give me some advise I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is to set up a height constraint on the TextView, add key value observer for `contentSize` property of a textview, and then manipulate the height constraint of a TextView on each `contentSize` change.
Please find a demo project here https://github.com/achikin/adjustabletextview

Comment: I downloaded your example project and that is exactly what I am looking for. However when I try to use it in my project I get the error: `Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints` `<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14755f1f0 V:[UITextView:0x147855e00'Details'(-51)]>` on the line `constraint.constant = constraint.constant + dy;`. Did you encounter this problem at any point?

Comment: It seems that the Text View disappears when the constraint is broken

Comment: @m1234 that has happened to me before because of too many constraints set or some constraints being to strict. Try to remove bottom constraint if you have one or make it <= instead of exact value. Just bear in mind that textview will grow down, so there should be no constraints preventing it from doing so.

Comment: Ok I will play around with constraints. The only issue is that I have a view below my Text View that I want to move down as the text view get larger

Comment: @m1234 not a big deal. Update the github project - I've added a view that goes down as you type more lines. With today's autolayout capabilities it's just the matter of setting the right constraints :)

Comment: You are my hero! Thank you so much for your help! I got it working after playing with the constraints for a bit!

Comment: @AntonChikin Any chance you can update your demo project to Swift 4?

Comment: @chickenparm, very unlikely. Why can't you do it by yourself?

Comment: @AntonChikin I tried and ran into some issues. Will try again.

Comment: @chickenparm the thing is that I was a seasoned ios developer, did several projects using Objc and Swift and abandoned it around Swift version 3. So I'm on the same page with you.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [UITextViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/) methods, especially at `- textViewDidChange:` method. Detect text changes on your `textView`, then adjust its height like so:

Objective-C:

```
CGRect frame;
frame = textiew.frame;
frame.size.height = [textView contentSize].height;
textView.frame = frame;
```

Swift:

```
let frame = textView.frame
frame.size.height = textView.contentSize.height
textView.frame = frame
```

Comment: In the world of AutoLayout it is not a good idea to manipulate either size or position of a view directly.